# Store time ranges - best practice

Tags: sql, performance, azure, azure-storage

I have an Azure account on which I can use one SQL database and the storage services - tables, blobs, queue - (nothing else due to budget constraints and the solution must be as cheap as possible; I am inclined to use the storage services as much as possible).

Our application generates some events and we want to be able to see how many events per day were generated and compute some averages.

I am looking for solution to store the events, counts and days when the events happened. The current solution that I have uses two SQL tables:

Events

- EventId (int)

EventData

- EventId (int) // ref to the Events table
- Date (date time) // stores the day when the data was received
- Count (int) // stores the number of events with that Id from that day

The problem that I'm facing: the EventData table has too much data. If we have X events and Y days for each event, the event data will store X*Y rows.

What other options are there to store the EventData and still be able to do (reasonable) fast reporting on it? I was thinking about actually storing event data as a blob and maybe keep only the last, let's say, 7 days in SQL.

Comment: how much is `too much data`. How many unique eventId's do you have? If you're already paying for the SQL Database, even the minimum 1GB version, you're data footprint should be tiny unless your dealing with hundreds of thousands of different event types over years.

Answer (score 0):

You could just flatten your structure and move to table storage ([How to use Table Storage])[1](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/) instead.  Not knowing what your data size or cost limit is it's hard to come up with the best solution.